# Synchronize only specfic group members of Magento to mailchimpg?

Tags: magento, mailchimp

I have integrated magemonkey mailchimp extension to my magento 1.7. Its working fine, all the magento mambers who are subscribed to magento are automatically synchronized with mailchimp list. But my client asked me to synchronize only the members who are added to wholesaler group of magento independent of whether they subscribed or not.
Situation:
I have developed a custom module which allows users to request for special group i.e. wholesaler. So if we add them to wholesaler group, we want them to be automatically added in our mailchimp list. Please suggest if you have any solution or any idea??

Comment: What does ebizmarts have to say about it?

Comment: Nothing i didn't find anything regarding this on their forum.